# Show that if <S2;S2,s> =>* <S2,s'>, it is not necessarily the case that <S1,s> =>* s'

Tags: formal-languages, operational-semantics

I am trying to solve this proof.

In structural semantics I need to proof that:

```
If <S1;S2,s> =>* <S2,s'>, then it is not necessarily needed that
<S1,s> =>* s'
```

I tried many things but I am not able to "break" the No Interference Lemma thay says:

```
 <S1;S2,s> =>k s' means that
 Exists an state s0 such that
 <S1,s> =>k1 s0 and <S2,s0> =>k2 s', k=k1+k2
```